# Refresh template in Keystone js

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, handlebars.js, keystonejs

I create 2 models in keystone. One is CD_Book, second is Musicians. I try connect this two collections when I open CD_Book view. I want display musicians from cd so I create this query:

```
        keystone.list('CD_Book').model.findOne({
            slug: locals.filters.cdbook
        }).exec(function(err, result) {
            locals.data.cdbook = result;
            let musiciansString = result.musicians
            musiciansTab = musiciansString.split(',');
            for (let i = 0; i < musiciansTab.length; i++) {
                keystone.list("Musician").model.findOne({
                    "title": musiciansTab[i].trim()
                }).exec(function(err, result) {
                    locals.data.musicians.push(result);
                    console.log(locals.data.musicians);
                });
            }
            next(err);
        });
```

And it's of course work and in console.log I get all musician data what i want, but it doesn't display in .hbs template. How should I refresh/update template after find all musicians? Maybe it's not the best way to achieve this (by using for loop)

Answer (score 1):

Your **findOne** calls are asynchronous so **next()** gets called before they finish.

Therefore, your template will be rendered before the data is available in **locals.data.musicians**.

You could try using **find** instead of **findOne** to get all musicians in one go and then set that to **locals** once retrieved.

You can then call **next()** when done to continue on to render the template.

Try something like this:

```
keystone.list('CD_Book').model
  .findOne({ slug: locals.filters.cdbook })
  .exec()
  .then(result => {

    locals.data.cdbook = result

    let musiciansString = result.musicians
    let musiciansTab = musiciansString
      .split(',')
      .map(musician => musician.trim())

    return keystone.list("Musician").model
      .find({ "title": { $in: musiciansTab } })
      .exec()

  })
  .then(result => {

    locals.data.musicians = result
    console.log(locals.data.musicians)
    next()

  })
  .catch(err => {
    next(err)
  })
```

I hope this helps.